# Applying \nouppercaseheads to section headers only in memoir

Tags: header-footer, memoir, capitalization

How would one apply `\nouppercaseheads` only to section headers when using the `memoir` document class?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Define a new pagestyle 'rgheadings'
\copypagestyle{rgheadings}{headings}
\makeheadrule{rgheadings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
% remove 'chapter' of headings style
\addtopsmarks{rgheadings}{}{
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{}{. \space}
}

% remove number section of headings style
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  %i need \nouppercaseheads only section
  \createmark{section} {right}{nonumber}{}{}
}

% define secao com letra minuscula
\def\sectionmark#1{\markright{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{rgheadings}

\chapter{Memoir with headings style}

\section{Mysection}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine `\sectionmark`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{headings}
\def\sectionmark#1{\markright{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Memoir with headings style}

\section{My section}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This time, your answer is the way to go. :-)

Comment: @lockstep: well, it's a tie then :-)

Comment: Not work. See my update post.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Move `\pagestyle{rgheadings}` *before* `\def\sectionmark#1{\markright{#1}}`, as Gonzola did with `headings` in his answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina How reinsert section number, example, 1.1 My section?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva use something like  \def\sectionmark#1{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}